# How to make a political figure to not giving speech about his political vision in an event?

Tags: presidential-election, policy

I am about to make an event and going to invite some political figures. The event must be a politic free event. But, I can't control the action of these political figures. This year is the year leading up to the presidential election in my country. So, the chance of promoting one of the president candidate is very likely to happen.

The political guests are supposed to give a speech and make small talk with other guests. There are no discussions.

How to professionally make the political figure to not speak about politic in the event?

Comment: If you're asking that question you're probably not in a position to organize an event where said leaders would actually show up.

Comment: I am one of the committee. The task should be in my leader's job. But, he too can't figure out the answer.

Comment: Again, the most likely answer is that your event is not big enough for those people to actually show up. If it was, you'd know the answer.

Comment: This seems more about how to convey your desires to someone than about politics proper; you can ask the politicians but you cannot "force" them. A good beginning would be filtering out those politicians who cannot enter "neutral mode", then explaining the candidates the objective of the organization and your desire of a neutral speech so they can assess if they can/want to give "institutional" speechs. And cross your fingers so no big politics news compel your guest to talk about it. Timing is important, too (if elections are near it could be more difficult).

Comment: Maybe https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit, but I am not completely sure. Check their FAQs.

Comment: Can you clarify a couple of points please.  First, which country are you in? (your profile suggests Indonesia)  Secondly I find it surprising that you invite politicians to a "politic free event" Could you give some more details on the nature of the event. Why it must be "politic free" and why you would ask politicians to speak at such an event.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. **"formal" promise.**

   Make them sign a pledge not to discuss politics and probably specific topics (so they won't weasel out with '*but this isn't politics*'). If they violate this, it gives attack fodder to their political opponents - "he broke the pledge to politicize event".

   This depends on how much the political figure wishes to be at your event - chances are they'd prefer to stay away rather than sign a pledge, in most cases, unless they *really* wish to be included for some reason, which is unlikely.
2. **Control purse strings, or be an influencer otherwise**

   If you're a big time donor or otherwise have big political influence (may be a celebrity who can make a lot of waves), you can leverage that.
3. **MAD**

   Invite two political opponents and publicly announce that both are not to politicize the event. The one who does, will look far worse than one who doesn't, and wouldn't want to risk that for a minor win of scoring some rhethorical point.